# Matplotlib set colors based on values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 2D numpy array containing values ranging from 0 to 4.
To make my graph more readable, I would like to assign colors according to the values in my numpy:
0: transparent (None) | 1: blue | 2: green | 3: red | 4: orange

I thought I had succeeded but my colors are random. And it is enough that a value is missing in my Numpy (no value 2) and that shifts everything :/

Do you have an idea ?
Here is my basic code to better understand the syntax

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size= (601,1031)
coordinates = np.zeros(size)
#fill my Numpy with 1/2/3/4
coordinatesMRE = np.random.randint(0,5,(601,1031))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
img = plt.imread("map.png") #Background img
ax.imshow(img, aspect='auto')
plt.axis('off')

plt.imshow(coordinatesMRE) #print color on my graph
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful

Comment: You can try `imshow(..., vmin=0, vmax=4)` to have a fixed mapping between values and colors.   With a `ListedColormap` you can fix some colors, e.g. `imshow(..., cmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(['none', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'orange']))`.